# Django: one authentication backend per user model

Tags: django, authentication, model, backend

In my Django application I need multiple type of Django users:
 1. A typical admin user which is identified by email and authenticated with password
 2. A remote application which connects to django and authenticates with pre-shared key and tokens. The email is not required for such type of user

Every type of user has different associated attributes. I know that I can extend User model in Django.
I already created email authentication backend. But this works for all the accounts, including the remote applications ones.

Is there any effective way to create a auth backend for a type of user?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authentication backend for the remote application and show it in your settings like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'path.to.email.authentication',
    'path.to.remote.app.authentication',
)
```

This way, Django will try to use the email authentication first and if that fails will try the remote app authentication.

You can read about custom authentication backends [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable for some of you users password authentication you can use [`set_unusable_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password). From the docs:

> Marks the user as having no password set. This isn’t the same as having a blank string for a password. check_password() for this user will never return True. Doesn’t save the User object.
>
> You may need this if authentication for your application takes place against an existing external source such as an LDAP directory.